# why my gps coordinate is being displayed zero?

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I'm making this simple app where when a button is placed users gps location should be displayed and it works fine with emulator but when i try that in a real phone both longitude and latitude are zero.

this is my code:
Main Activiy:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TextView longS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longi);
        final TextView latiS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lati);

        Button btn_show_location = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        btn_show_location.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
             public void onClick(View view) {  
                 LocationManager mlocManager=null;  
                 LocationListener mlocListener;  
                 mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
                 mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();  
                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);  

                if (mlocManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {  
                    if(MyLocationListener.latitude>0)  
                    {  
                         longS.setText("Latitude:- " + MyLocationListener.latitude);  
                         latiS.setText("Longitude:- " + MyLocationListener.longitude + '\n');  
                     }  
                     else  
                     {  
                          longS.setText("Please wait");
                      }  
                  } else {  
                      Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
                                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
                            startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent); 
                  }  

              }  
         });  
    }
```

MyLocationListener:

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {  

    public static double latitude;  
    public static double longitude;  

    @Override  
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)  
    {  
       // loc.getLatitude();  
        //loc.getLongitude();  
        latitude=loc.getLatitude();  
        longitude=loc.getLongitude();  
    }  

    @Override  
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)  
    {  
        //print "Currently GPS is Disabled";  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)  
    {  
        //print "GPS got Enabled";  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)  
    {  
    }  
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.databasecollect"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: are you sure that the gps is connected ?

Comment: What phone are you using?

Comment: you should learn about callbacks/listeners ...  you  only set text right after requestLocationUpdates ... but there is a big chance that you will not get gps fix between this two calls ...

Comment: yes gps is working @blackbelt

Comment: sony xperia c @Hasslarn

Comment: i didn't get your point.. please elaborate :) @Selvin

Comment: ok shorten version: you have a problems with code flow (what line is running first and why), you just don't get it ... the `onLocationChanged` can be called after `longS.setText("Latitude:- " + MyLocationListener.latitude);` then obviously MyLocationListener.latitude is 0 ...